# Why can't I create Leadbolt SDK with Notification Ads?

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, ads, leadbolt

From the publisher page, there are options for

- Quick Start Ads
- Display Ads
- Icon Ads
- Notification Ads

But for some reason only the Display Ads checkbox can be selected.
I am unsure why I can't select the others, I am currently trying in implement Notification Ads? Here's how it looks..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has disallowed notification ads. As per the latest policy:

> Apps and their ads must not add homescreen shortcuts, browser
>   bookmarks, or icons on the user's device as a service to third parties
>   or for advertising purposes. **Apps and their ads must not display
>   advertisements through system level notifications on the user's
>   device**, unless the notifications derive from an integral feature
>   provided by the installed app.

Among a number of changes, Google has specifically disallowed advertisements through system level notifications. Apps that create home screen shortcuts, browser bookmarks, or home screen icons on the user’s device are also disallowed.

For existing apps on Google Play, the new policies will be enforced on 23rd September 2013.

**If you are using LeadBolt’s notification or icon ads you will need to update your app before the relevant date.**